# How do you manage missing date in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, missing-data

I have a dataframe with multiple columns with date that I want to convert to integer with the toordinal method, but there are some missing dates and I would like to know how to manage them to be able to make the conversion.

I tried this :

```
dates['date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())
```

And I have the error :

```
ValueError: NaTType does not support toordinal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module. Note that `NaT` is converted to `1` by `datetime.toordinal`. You may, if you wish, replace this with a value of your choice as a separate step.

Data from @jezrael.

```
from datetime import datetime

rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=5)
dates = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng}) 
dates.loc[6, 'date'] = np.nan

dates['date_ordinal'] = dates['date'].apply(datetime.toordinal)

print(dates)

        date  date_ordinal
0 2017-04-03        736422
1 2017-04-04        736423
2 2017-04-05        736424
3 2017-04-06        736425
4 2017-04-07        736426
6        NaT             1
```

Comment: Ty it worked, and with that I dont have to apply the function

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```
dates['date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal() if pd.notna(x) else 0)
```

Comment: I got the same error : ValueError: NaTType does not support toordinal, while trying this one

Comment: Thanks @RodrigueKap, I should have used `pd.notna(x)` instead of relying on Python's built in falsey check (I fixed the code above). Have you reviewed https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html? It may be helpful. Cheers!

Comment: now it works thanks. I've seen the doc but they didn't go in depth on how to manage missing dates :/